# Collaborate via a private/unlisted cloud folder without login

Tags: file-sharing, cloud-storage

I'd like to give users a link to a web-ui cloud folder, onto which they could upload [large] files without bothering to login to some account.

OneDrive is a good candidate due to the 15GB free storage, however, users that would like to upload content need to be logged-in with a Microsoft id.

Google Drive and Dropbox introduce similar behaviors.

I also looked at copy.com that doesn't offer a hyperlink to an upload folder.

Anybody familiar with something that could meet the above requirements?

Comment: Questions seeking [service recommendations](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic), are no on topic here at Superuser.  Citrix has a file sharing service that might fit your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ramhound. I already got flogged once on StackOverflow for an off topic question, so this time I tried finding the right place to ask. I thought about Server Fault, but it's a site for admins, so I chose SuperUser which is a "site for computer enthusiasts and power users". It almost feels like StackExchange needs to raise a Q&A site for asking where's the right place to post a question. If this is not the place, then can you please let me know which StackExchange site is the right one for this question? Thanks again.

Comment: There isn't a place for service recommendations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dropbox has feature that allows people without an account to upload files to Dropbox users' folders.

It is Called *File Requests*. It gives the option to upload files into your Dropbox account and into a folder of your choosing.

Coonect to [http://www.dropbox.com/requests](http://Dropbox.com/requests), specify what file or files you’re looking for and you’re then provided a link you can distribute to the people without an account.

Comment: Thanks jcbermu. I didn't check Dropbox because of the 2GB limit in the free edition, but that's an interesting path to follow. I'll mark this as the accepted answer, but I still hope for other answers with more alternatives. (P.S.. like you avatar :)